# Migrating data from an old to a new schema

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-migration

I have two tables from two different schemas. I want to move data from a table in the old schema to the table in the new schema.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

INSERT into newdb.Addresses (addressID, contactID, primaryFlag, type, address1, address2, poBox, city, state, zip, country, email)
SELECT address_id, contact_id, is_primary_address, 

    (SELECT address_type
    FROM test.address_types, test.contact_addresses
    WHERE test.contact_addresses.address_type_id = test.address_types.address_type_id),

    address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_2, address_city, address_state, address_zip,

    (SELECT country
    FROM test.countries, test.contact_addresses
    WHERE test.contact_addresses.address_country_id = test.countries.country_id),

    address_email

FROM test.contact_addresses;
```

Sorry if it's sloppily typed. Basically, when I run the query, it says that the subquery returns more than one row. How do I restructure the query so that what is returned in the subqueries is the row that the engine is currently iterating through (therefore, only one row is returned)?

Comment: Can you please show your create tables? and can you explain that final data set that you are looking for. Both sub queries will need a limit 1 added to them for them to work but I don't this this will give you what you need. you must re-write this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the test.contact_addresses in the subqueries:

```
SELECT address_id, contact_id, is_primary_address, 

     (SELECT address_type
      FROM test.address_types AS at
      WHERE at.address_type_id = ca.address_type_id),

address_line_1, ....

FROM test.contact_addresses AS ca;
```

This way, SQL selects the one that equals the adress_type_id in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

The select part of you query is missing columns as the columns in the insert do not match the column in the select. Also, you do not need to inner join the sub queried to the outside table all over again.

Try changing your query above to the following

this will perform much quicker that the query you have above and it will give you what you need.

```
INSERT INTO newdb.Addresses (.......)
SELECT a.address_id, a.contact_id, a.is_primary_address, t.address_type, c.country, a.address_email
FROM test.contact_addresses AS a
INNER JOIN test.address_types AS t ON t.address_type_id = a.address_type_id
INNER JOIN test.countries AS c ON c.country_id = a.country_id;
```